# Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ convergent with $|x_n+1| \le \frac{b_n}{n^2+1}$ and $b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(b_n)$ and $(x_n)$ be a real sequence such that $\displaystyle b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k$ and $|x_n+1| \le \frac{b_n}{n^2+1}$ for all positive integer $n$.
Show that $(x_n)$ convergent and find its limit.

**Attempt:**
Notice that
$$|x_n+1| \le \frac{n^2+n}{2n^2+2} \iff -\frac{3n^2+n+2}{2n^2+2} \le x_n \le -\frac{n^2-n+2}{2n^2+2}.$$
I've shown that $(x_n)$ is bounded; that is, $|x_n| \le \frac{5}{2}$ for all positive integer $n$.
But, I can't be able yet to show that $(x_n)$ is a monotonic sequence.

Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hi, you can't prove, that $(x_n) _n$ converges. Observe, that $x_n=(-1) +(-1) ^n\frac 14$ fulfills your condition.

Answer (score 2):

It is false.

Let $x_n=-1$ for all odd integer $n$, and $x_n=-1+\frac1{100}$ for all even interger $n$. It satisfies all conditions, but the sequence is divergent.